# Windows installer complains that it can only be installed on a primary partition

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, system-installation

I have Linux mint installed on my system as primary partition.

I want to install windows 8 along side with it (Dual boot).

But when I try to install windows 8 installer says (windows can only be install Primary partition).

I have only 1 primary partition in which Linux is running, other are extended or logical ones.

[image: Partition Details]

I want to use my last Partition (Label : Apps) for installing Windows.

Can I convert a logical partition to primary or any other better suggestion?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: You need to change you partition structure so that there is at least one more primary partition.

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs to have a primary partition for some system files. It can use logical partitions, but only as a second partition for extra data. So you'll need to shrink the extended partition to make room.

Fortunately, the partition you want to reuse is the last one in disk order. So

1. Delete the last logical partition `/dev/sda8`.
2. Shrink the extended partition to extend only to the end of `/dev/sda7`.
3. Create a primary partition in the now-free space. (You can let the Windows installer do it instead.)

You can do this in GParted.

I think you'll need to boot from the rescue CD/USB, as otherwise Parted won't be able to resize the extended partition while a logical partition inside it is in use. If you don't have rescue media handy, you can use the [GParted live CD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).